# Should we change the word "Answer" in meta posts that is tagged with "discussion" to "Posts"?

Tags: discussion, answers, meta, wording

In meta, we can have discussion posts, which is indicated by the discussion tag. But IMO, discussion is not supposed to have questions and answers. Everyone seems to be sharing his/her ideas or opinions by posting an "Answer". That makes little sense, doesn't it?

I m suggesting to change texts like this

- 10 answers
- add an answer
- your answer
- and other related stuff

To

- 10 Posts
- add a post
- your post

etc. if the question is tagged with discussion.

Will this be a good idea? I think changing this on all sites requires the change of a lot of code.

Comment: I couldn't find any meta posts from users that didn't engage in a discussion because they wanted to *post* something instead of answering. Do you have some evidence that users are actually confused?

Answer (score 10):

No.

The word "post" is already in use, it means either a question or an answer.

Changing "answers" to be "posts" will be highly confusing.

Answer (score 6):

This is a bad idea and not only because the word 'post' is already used for questions and answers (so a page with 10 answers has 11 posts).

Another thing is: even though it is meta, every question should still be a question, and every answer should still be a an answer. Comments are still comments. Changing the name of 'answers' will make the working of the site confusing.

Comment: Not for the first time, you "complete" my answer. Thanks! :)

Comment: Not for the first time you beat me to it. Thanks back :)